# Java code throws execption "Error: Could not open Parameters.properties, please make sure it's in your current working directory"

Tags: java, string, working-directory, application.properties

I have absolutely no coding experience outside of some R tutorials and am trying to execute a code that provided in .class file. I have used jd-gui-windows-1.6.6 to save it as .java file and attempted to run it with cmd and Netbeans. The error occurs around line 46. The other files are in proper .FASTA format except for the properties which is set one default.

```
/*     */ import java.io.BufferedWriter;
/*     */ import java.io.FileInputStream;
/*     */ import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
/*     */ import java.io.FileReader;
/*     */ import java.io.FileWriter;
/*     */ import java.io.IOException;
/*     */ import java.io.InputStream;
/*     */ import java.io.InputStreamReader;
/*     */ import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
/*     */ import java.net.URL;
/*     */ import java.net.URLConnection;
/*     */ import java.net.URLEncoder;
/*     */ import java.util.Properties;
/*     */ 
/*     */ public class RNA22v2 {
/*  24 */   private static Properties appProps = null;
/*     */   
/*  25 */   private String mirseq = null;
/*     */   
/*  26 */   private String transcriptseq = null;
/*     */   
/*  27 */   private String outputfile = null;
/*     */   
/*  28 */   private String outputformat = null;
/*     */   
/*  29 */   private String seedmismatchsallowed = null;
/*     */   
/*  30 */   private String seedsize = null;
/*     */   
/*  31 */   private String minpairmatchs = null;
/*     */   
/*  32 */   private String minenergy = null;
/*     */   
/*  33 */   private String maxguwobbles = null;
/*     */   
/*  34 */   private String threshold = null;
/*     */   
/*     */   private BufferedWriter out;
/*     */   
/*     */   private BufferedReader inMirs;
/*     */   
/*     */   public static void main(String[] args) {
/*  41 */     RNA22v2 thisclass = new RNA22v2();
/*  42 */     appProps = new Properties();
/*     */     try {
/*  46 */       thisclass.LoadPropertyFiles("Parameters.properties");
/*  48 */     } catch (Exception e) {
/*  50 */       System.out.println("Error: Could not open Parameters.properties, please make sure it's in your current working directory");
/*     */       return;
/*     */     } 
/*     */     try {
/*  56 */       thisclass.mirseq = appProps.getProperty("mirseq");
/*  57 */       thisclass.transcriptseq = appProps.getProperty("transcriptseq");
/*  58 */       thisclass.outputfile = appProps.getProperty("outputfile");
/*  59 */       thisclass.outputformat = appProps.getProperty("outputformat");
/*  60 */       thisclass.seedmismatchsallowed = appProps.getProperty("seedmismatchsallowed");
/*  61 */       thisclass.seedsize = appProps.getProperty("seedsize");
/*  62 */       thisclass.minpairmatchs = appProps.getProperty("minpairmatchs");
/*  63 */       thisclass.minenergy = appProps.getProperty("minenergy");
/*  64 */       thisclass.maxguwobbles = appProps.getProperty("maxguwobbles");
/*  65 */       thisclass.threshold = appProps.getProperty("threshold");
/*  67 */       if (thisclass.mirseq == null || thisclass.transcriptseq == null || thisclass.outputfile == null || thisclass.outputformat == null || thisclass.seedmismatchsallowed == null || thisclass.seedsize == null || thisclass.minpairmatchs == null || thisclass.minenergy == null || thisclass.maxguwobbles == null || thisclass.threshold == null) {
/*  69 */         System.out.println("Error: Missing value in Parameters.properties file");
/*     */         return;
/*     */       } 
/*  73 */       System.out.println("Fetching results from server");
/*  74 */       thisclass.getResults();
/*  75 */       System.out.println("Completed program, please see output file " + thisclass.outputfile + " for the results");
/*  77 */     } catch (Exception e) {
/*  79 */       System.out.println("Error: unexpected exception caught with callstack of:");
/*  80 */       e.printStackTrace();
/*     */     } 
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   private void getResults() throws IOException {
/*     */     try {
/*  88 */       this.out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.outputfile));
/*  90 */     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
/*  92 */       System.out.println("Error: unable to write to your output file (" + this.outputfile + ")");
/*     */       return;
/*     */     } 
/*     */     try {
/*  99 */       this.inMirs = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.mirseq));
/* 101 */     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
/* 103 */       System.out.println("Error: unable to open input file (" + this.mirseq + ") for reading");
/*     */       return;
/*     */     } 
/* 107 */     int lastMir = 0;
/* 108 */     int numMirs = 0;
/* 109 */     while (lastMir == 0) {
/* 111 */       String[] miR = new String[100];
/*     */       int m;
/* 114 */       for (m = 0; m < 100; m += 2) {
/* 116 */         numMirs++;
/* 117 */         miR[m] = this.inMirs.readLine();
/* 118 */         if (miR[m] == null) {
/* 120 */           lastMir = 1;
/*     */           break;
/*     */         } 
/* 123 */         if (miR[m].charAt(0) != '>') {
/* 125 */           System.out.println("Error: Expected header in FASTA formatted miR input file (" + miR[m] + ") and did not receive, exiting..  Remember, no empty lines are allowed and the miR sequence must be on one line");
/*     */           break;
/*     */         } 
/* 129 */         miR[m + 1] = this.inMirs.readLine();
/* 130 */         if (miR[m + 1] == null) {
/* 132 */           System.out.println("Error: Sequence not specified for miR " + miR[m] + ", exiting..");
/*     */           break;
/*     */         } 
/* 135 */         if (miR[m + 1].charAt(0) == '>') {
/* 137 */           System.out.println("Error: Sequence expected but received a header instead, invalid FASTA formatted miR input file, exiting..");
/*     */           break;
/*     */         } 
/*     */       } 
/* 142 */       if (m != 0) {
/*     */         BufferedReader inTranscripts;
/*     */         try {
/* 147 */           inTranscripts = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.transcriptseq));
/* 149 */         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
/* 151 */           System.out.println("Error: unable to open input file (" + this.transcriptseq + ") for reading");
/*     */           return;
/*     */         } 
/* 154 */         int lastTranscript = 0;
/* 155 */         int numTranscripts = 0;
/* 156 */         String lastline = "";
/* 158 */         while (lastTranscript == 0) {
/* 160 */           String[] transcripts = new String[2];
/* 161 */           transcripts[0] = "";
/* 162 */           transcripts[1] = "";
/* 163 */           numTranscripts++;
/* 166 */           if (lastline.equals("")) {
/* 168 */             lastline = inTranscripts.readLine();
/* 169 */             if (lastline == null) {
/* 171 */               lastTranscript = 1;
/*     */               break;
/*     */             } 
/* 174 */             transcripts[0] = lastline;
/*     */           } else {
/* 178 */             transcripts[0] = lastline;
/*     */           } 
/* 180 */           if (transcripts[0].charAt(0) != '>') {
/* 182 */             System.out.println("Error: Expected header in FASTA formatted transcript input file (" + transcripts[0] + ") and did not receive, exiting..");
/*     */             return;
/*     */           } 
/*     */           while (true) {
/* 190 */             lastline = inTranscripts.readLine();
/* 191 */             if (lastline == null) {
/* 193 */               lastTranscript = 1;
/*     */               break;
/*     */             } 
/* 196 */             if (!lastline.equals("") && 
/* 197 */               lastline.charAt(0) == '>')
/*     */               break; 
/* 200 */             transcripts[1] = String.valueOf(transcripts[1]) + lastline;
/*     */           } 
/* 204 */           if (!transcripts[0].equals("")) {
/* 206 */             if (transcripts[1].equals("")) {
/* 208 */               System.out.println("Error: Sequence not specified for transcript " + transcripts[0] + " " + transcripts[1] + ", exiting..");
/*     */               return;
/*     */             } 
/* 212 */             int retry = 0;
/* 213 */             int done = 0;
/* 214 */             while (done == 0 && retry <= 10) {
/*     */               try {
/* 218 */                 System.out.println("Processing up to miR # " + numMirs + " and transcript # " + numTranscripts);
/* 219 */                 GetRemoteResults(miR, m, transcripts, 2);
/* 220 */                 done = 1;
/* 222 */               } catch (Exception e) {
/* 224 */                 retry++;
/* 225 */                 System.out.println("Error: unexpected exception caught fetching data from rna22v2 server, retrying (max = 11 times), retry #" + retry + ", NO DATA HAS BEEN LOST YET!!");
/* 226 */                 e.printStackTrace();
/*     */                 try {
/* 228 */                   Thread.sleep(10000L);
/* 229 */                 } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
/* 230 */                   System.out.println("Error: unexpected exception caught while sleeping for 10 seconds...");
/* 231 */                   e1.printStackTrace();
/*     */                 } 
/*     */               } 
/*     */             } 
/* 235 */             if (done == 0) {
/* 237 */               System.out.println("Error: uncoverable errors after maximum # of retries, exiting...");
/*     */               return;
/*     */             } 
/*     */           } 
/*     */         } 
/* 243 */         inTranscripts.close();
/*     */       } 
/*     */     } 
/* 247 */     this.out.close();
/* 248 */     this.inMirs.close();
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   private void GetRemoteResults(String[] miR, int mMaxIndex, String[] transcripts, int tMaxIndex) throws Exception {
/* 253 */     String MiRSeq = "";
/* 254 */     String TranscriptSeq = "";
/*     */     int i;
/* 256 */     for (i = 0; i < mMaxIndex; i++) {
/* 258 */       if (i != 0)
/* 260 */         MiRSeq = String.valueOf(MiRSeq) + "\n"; 
/* 262 */       MiRSeq = String.valueOf(MiRSeq) + miR[i];
/*     */     } 
/* 264 */     for (i = 0; i < tMaxIndex; i++) {
/* 266 */       if (i != 0)
/* 268 */         TranscriptSeq = String.valueOf(TranscriptSeq) + "\n"; 
/* 270 */       TranscriptSeq = String.valueOf(TranscriptSeq) + transcripts[i];
/*     */     } 
/* 274 */     String data = 
/* 275 */       "outputformat=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.outputformat, "UTF-8") + 
/* 276 */       "&mirseq=" + URLEncoder.encode(MiRSeq, "UTF-8") + 
/* 277 */       "&transcriptseq=" + URLEncoder.encode(TranscriptSeq, "UTF-8") + 
/* 278 */       "&seedmismatchsallowed=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.seedmismatchsallowed, "UTF-8") + 
/* 279 */       "&seedsize=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.seedsize, "UTF-8") + 
/* 280 */       "&minpairmatchs=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.minpairmatchs, "UTF-8") + 
/* 281 */       "&minenergy=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.minenergy, "UTF-8") + 
/* 282 */       "&maxguwobbles=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.maxguwobbles, "UTF-8") + 
/* 283 */       "&threshold=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.threshold, "UTF-8") + 
/* 284 */       "&javaappversion=" + URLEncoder.encode("v5", "UTF-8");
/* 287 */     URL url = new URL("https://cm.jefferson.edu/rna22/Interactive/AJAXController");
/* 289 */     URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
/* 290 */     conn.setConnectTimeout(20000);
/* 291 */     conn.setReadTimeout(180000);
/* 305 */     conn.setDoOutput(true);
/* 306 */     OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
/* 307 */     wr.write(data);
/* 308 */     wr.flush();
/* 311 */     BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
/* 313 */     String fulloutput = "";
/*     */     String line;
/* 314 */     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
/* 316 */       if (line.startsWith("Error:")) {
/* 318 */         System.out.println(line);
/* 319 */         System.out.println("Exiting application because of error above");
/* 320 */         System.exit(0);
/*     */         continue;
/*     */       } 
/* 324 */       fulloutput = String.valueOf(fulloutput) + line + "\n";
/*     */     } 
/* 328 */     this.out.write(fulloutput);
/* 329 */     this.out.flush();
/* 330 */     wr.close();
/* 331 */     rd.close();
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   public void LoadPropertyFiles(String path) throws Exception {
/* 340 */     InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
/* 341 */     appProps.load(in);
/* 342 */     in.close();
/*     */   }
/*     */ }


/* Location:              C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\rna\!\!\RNA22v2.class
 * Java compiler version: 6 (50.0)
 * JD-Core Version:       1.1.3
 */
```

Comment: On line 50 print actual exception using `e.printStackTrace();`. You may not have permission to read the file.  Also, print current working directory using `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` and make sure the .properties file is there.

Comment: Why are you trying to decompile and recompile code if you have now programming experience? Note that decompilers not always work flawlessly and this can introduce other errors as well. In your case the file `Parameters.properties` simply doesn't seem to be present in the directory you're trying to run the application from.

Comment: I need to run the code to not have to do something manually over a hundred times.